# Issue in installing grunt-cli

Tags: gruntjs

I'm trying to install grunt-cli. Here is the command I'm executing:

```
  npm install -g grunt-cli
```

But I'm getting the following error message. My machine is running under corporate proxy. Is it due to that?? Could someone please let me know how to resolve this issue.

```
  npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-cli
  npm http 304 http://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-cli
  npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-cli/-/grunt-cli-0.1.13.tgz
  npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-cli/-/grunt-cli-0.1.13.tgz
  npm ERR! Error: shasum check failed for C:\Users\781650\AppData\Local\Temp\npm-6
  640-cHN2e4JV\1401080165006-0.9552419183310121\tmp.tgz
  npm ERR! Expected: e9ebc4047631f5012d922770c39378133cad10f4
  npm ERR! Actual:   11b711d30f410c53585e0dee9d932cb24d49bab9
  npm ERR! From:     http://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-cli/-/grunt-cli-0.1.13.tgz
  npm ERR!     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\sha\index.
  js:38:8
  npm ERR!     at ReadStream.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm
  \node_modules\sha\index.js:85:7)
  npm ERR!     at ReadStream.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)
  npm ERR!     at _stream_readable.js:920:16
  npm ERR!     at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
  npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
  npm ERR! including the npm and node versions, at:
  npm ERR!     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

  npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
  npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nod
  ejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "grunt-cli"

  npm ERR! node -v v0.10.26
  npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.3
  npm ERR!
```

Comment: Try `npm cache clean` and `npm install -g grunt-cli` again.

Comment: @KyleRobinsonYoung No it does not work after doing what you have suggested.

Answer (score 0):

i guess most likely due to proxy, try to set the proxy

```
npm config set proxy xxx 
npm config set https-proxy xxx
```